# What is the heapspray technique and how to use it as reliably as possible?

Tags: attacks, heap-overflow

Can somebody explain the different steps to produce a *heapspray attack* (what are the needed vulnerabilities in the targeted software, what are the limitations of such technique, how to proceed, ...) and how to render it as reliable as possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Peter(corelanc0d3r) - Corelan team](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2011/12/31/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-11-heap-spraying-demystified/) has one of the best Buffer Overflow tutorials on the internet

Answer (score 1):

Heap Spraying is more the distraction used to enable someone to perform the actual attack.
It in itself does not compromise any security measure.  It is typically used in conjunction with injected code which is the payload. Think of it as a no op sled.